# What is the ideal way to listen for messages from Hubot scripts?

Tags: adapter, send, hubot

I want to create a hubot script that captures messages within a multiuser chat and record them including hubot.  The problem is that hubot does not hear itself.  It doesn't appear that adapters emit an event whenever a message is sent, so is there a recommended approach to listening to hubot messages?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  We have a deploy script that uses our same bot's API key to output commit messages, and we were trying to get him to also output a motivational image on deploy by having him listen to the regex `/\[Heroku\]/` but he doesn't respond to messages sent by himself - Is there any way to make this specific script respond to himself?

Answer (score 1):

We're using Hubot with HipChat, and have resorted to posting directly to HipChat's API when we want the bot to listen. Not ideal, but works.